# Rad Loading panel not showing

Tags: asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid

I'm trying to use telerik Rad loading panel with a rad pivotal grid but the loading panel doesn't show up.

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" runat="server"></telerik:RadScriptManager>

            <telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel ID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" runat="server">
            </telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel>


            <telerik:RadAjaxPanel ID="radAjaxPanel1" runat="server" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" Skin="Vista">


            <telerik:RadPivotGrid AllowPaging="true" PageSize="10" Width="800px" Height="400px"
            ID="RadPivotGrid1" runat="server" ColumnHeaderZoneText="ColumnHeaderZone" OnNeedDataSource="RadPivotGrid1_NeedDataSource">
            <ClientSettings EnableFieldsDragDrop="true">
                <Scrolling AllowVerticalScroll="true"></Scrolling>
            </ClientSettings>
            <Fields>
                <telerik:PivotGridRowField DataField="Animal" ZoneIndex="0">
                </telerik:PivotGridRowField>

                <telerik:PivotGridColumnField DataField="Product">
                </telerik:PivotGridColumnField>
                <telerik:PivotGridColumnField DataField="Recipe">
                </telerik:PivotGridColumnField>

            </Fields>

        </telerik:RadPivotGrid>

            </telerik:RadAjaxPanel>

    </form>
```

Answer (score -1):

When testing on your dev machine it is likely that the server operations are completed too quickly for you to notice the loading panel. Try adding a System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000); call to the Page_Load event to see if it will let you see it. If you see it - then it is there, it is the speed and lack of latency on localhost that prevents the human eye from noticing.